# How do I connect three routers to three hosts in mininet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mininet

I have this code that I am trying to use to connect three routers r1,r2,r3 together. I think I have to use switches to connect host nodes to the routers so each router is connected to a switch that is connected to a host. I have it working for 2 routers but I can't get it to work for three routers
I am using mininet to run the python script. Is there a way to add the ip addresses to the routing tables for the host. I am new to mininet so I am not familiar with connecting routers. I have to do this for 7 routers not just three but I am starting with 3 for now. Is there a better way to do this ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI


class LinuxRouter(Node):
    def config(self, **params):
        super(LinuxRouter, self).config(**params)
        self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1')

    def terminate(self):
        self.cmd('sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0')
        super(LinuxRouter, self).terminate()


class NetworkTopo(Topo):
    def build(self, **_opts):
        # Add 2 routers in two different subnets
        r1 = self.addHost('r1', cls=LinuxRouter, ip='10.0.0.1/24')
        r2 = self.addHost('r2', cls=LinuxRouter, ip='10.1.0.1/24')
        r3 = self.addHost('r3', cls=LinuxRouter, ip='10.2.0.1/24')

        # Add 2 switches
        s1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
        s2 = self.addSwitch('s2')
        s3 = self.addSwitch('s3')

        # Add host-switch links in the same subnet
        self.addLink(s1,
                     r1,
                     intfName2='r1-eth1',
                     params2={'ip': '10.0.0.1/24'})

        self.addLink(s2,
                     r2,
                     intfName2='r2-eth1',
                     params2={'ip': '10.1.0.1/24'})
                     
        self.addLink(s3,
                     r3,
                     intfName2='r3-eth1',
                     params2={'ip': '10.2.0.1/24'})
        
        # Add router-router link in a new subnet for the router-router connection
        self.addLink(r1,
                     r2,
                     intfName1='r1-eth2',
                     intfName2='r2-eth2',
                     params1={'ip': '10.100.0.1/24'},
                     params2={'ip': '10.100.0.2/24'})
        
        self.addLink(r1,
                     r2,
                     intfName1='r1-eth3',
                     intfName2='r2-eth3',
                     params1={'ip': '10.101.0.1/24'},
                     params2={'ip': '10.101.0.2/24'})
     
        
        # Adding hosts specifying the default route
        d1 = self.addHost(name='d1',
                          ip='10.0.0.251/24',
                          defaultRoute='via 10.0.0.1')
        d2 = self.addHost(name='d2',
                          ip='10.1.0.252/24',
                          defaultRoute='via 10.1.0.1')
        d3 = self.addHost(name='d3',
                          ip='10.1.0.253/24',
                          defaultRoute='via 10.1.0.1')

        # Add host-switch links
        self.addLink(d1, s1)
        self.addLink(d2, s2)
        self.addLink(d3, s2)


def run():
    topo = NetworkTopo()
    net = Mininet(topo=topo)

    # Add routing for reaching networks that aren't directly connected
    print info(net['r1'].cmd("ip route add 10.1.0.0/24 via 10.100.0.2 dev r1-eth2"))
    print info(net['r2'].cmd("ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.100.0.1 dev r2-eth2"))

    net.start()
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    run()
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out, general questions asking for guidance doesn't fit with SO's objectives.

Comment: Why do you need this at all? What is the benefit of trying to configure your own component to simply using the provided switch?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why router 3 is not working is because you have not connected it! So instead of

```
self.addLink(r1,
                     r2,
                     intfName1='r1-eth3',
                     intfName2='r2-eth3',
                     params1={'ip': '10.101.0.1/24'},
                     params2={'ip': '10.101.0.2/24'})
```

Use

```
self.addLink(r1,
                     r2,
                     intfName1='r1-eth0',
                     intfName2='r3-eth0',
                     params1={'ip': '10.101.0.1/24'},
                     params2={'ip': '10.101.0.2/24'})
```